# How do i check if there is ANYTHING inside my string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I seen people asking questions of "how do i check if there is specific text inside my string?"

i want to know how do i check if the string has anything inside of it.

Comment: If you want to check if a non-null string is empty, do `if (myString.Length == 0)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the static [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var test = string.Empty
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))
{
    // There is nothing in the string or its null
}
```

Comment: and how do i set an existing _String_ for the string from the "string.empty?"

Comment: You just pass the existing string to the `string.IsNullOrEmpty`method.

Comment: @jjm String.Empty is generally an empty string. like "". Two quotes and nothing in between. Just an explicit way to to that.

Comment: that what i thought but it gave me the CS0176 error.

Comment: jjm, can you include your code to your question so we can help you how to do it right?

Answer (score 3):

Addition to jisaak's answer, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mystring)` also helps if you consider a string consisting of `white-space` as containing nothing.